# Updating md5 passwords with the php password_hash function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a database with accounts that still use the MD5 algorithm which is old and unsafe, so I wanted to update the passwords with the password_hash function in php.

I made a login for users with a md5 password so they can be prompted with an update field to update their password. It all works and I see the new hash string in the database. But when I want to login using their new password it's just not possible.

I use a PDO update query to update the passwords, does anyone have a solution or know if this is even possible?

Thanks in advance,
Bram.

EDIT:

This is the code I use to verify the passwords.

```
if (password_verify($password, $rowofusers['passwordhere'])) {
       //code here
      }
```

Comment: `But when I want to login using their new password it's just not possible.` So perhaps show the code that your'e using for verifying the password on login?

Comment: You should post the relevant code.

Comment: What is the type and length of database field you store passwords in ?

Comment: Instead of asking the users to update their passwords you could check if the hash in the database start with $2y$, if it do continue logging in using password_verify, if not verify the password using md5 and if it is a match update what you store in the database. (Of course this require that you get login using bcrypt to work, and we need to see your code for that to be able to help you)

Comment: The type of the field is a Varchar and the lenght is 255 characters. I've updated the original post with the verifying script.

Comment: You've updated the post with a single line of code.... bwhat we can't see are any previous lines of code, that might show if you're manipulating `$password` in any way, because it should be exactly what is entered by the user; we can't see how you're retrieving `$rowofusers` from the database, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, the correct way to do this can be completely transparent to the user and should not require an "*update password prompt*".

When the user tries to log in take the following steps to modify your login process accordingly.

1. Check if the hash in the db starts with `$2y$` to determine if the password should be check with `md5` or `password_verify`. If it does start with `$2y$` then just use `password_verify` and ignore the remaining steps (*continuing on with the rest of your normal login process*).
2. If the password hash in the database does not start with `$2y$` then first, check the plain-text password against its `md5` hash.
3. If the plain-text password's hash doesn't matches the `md5` hash in your database continue with normal failed authentication process and ignore the remaining steps here
4. If the plain-text password's hash **does** match the `md5` hash in your database then take the plain-text password and run it through `password_hash` and update your database with the newly generated BCRYPT hash from `password_hash`.

You would have to keep this code in your login process until all passwords in your database have been updated and no remaining `md5` hashes are left. The user will never know that their password hash is updated and never be prompted to enter their password twice as it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Sheriff But until all passwords are updated and weak-hashed data are insecure. Therefore, until all password migrated into bcrypt which is the best solution tro harden the password storage?

Comment: @Dimitrios you can't _harden_ the md5 hashes. Until the user takes direct action, specifically to supply the plain text password, there is nothing that can be done about the existing md5 hashes in the database.