# How I can re-hash my user's a password using bcrypt in postgresql without iterating them in php?

Tags: php, postgresql, postgresql-11

In my database I use a weak hash, SHA1, for the password. I want to migrate them into a stronger hash (bcrypt). Usually it is done via the following php script:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id,password from users";
/**
* @var $pdo database connection
*/
$statement = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE users SET password = :password WHERE user_id = :user_id");

foreach( $pdo->query($sql) as $user)
{
   $password  = password_hash($user['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
   $statement->bindParam(':password',$password);   
   $statement->bindParam(':user_id',$user['user_id']);
   $stmt->execute();
}
```

But on large datasets will take too long to update. Therefore do you know a faster way to hash all user passwords in postgresql with a postgresql-native password updating?

Also the code above will run in a migration script and it may cause some delays in deployment as well.

Comment: What you are saying, makes little sense. The code you have shown appears to rely on being able to _read_ the clear-text password from the database. If that is possible - then you can not really have hashed them in the first place.

Comment: The `password`  field in table `et_users` contains the password hashed using a sha1 hash. What I actually want do is a double hash hashing the sha1 hashed password into bcrypt. Then upon login I will rehash it into bcrypt from plaintext.

Comment: `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` currently means bcrypt will be used, and PASSWORD_BCRYPT in turn means, it uses the CRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm - which PostgreSQL appears to support, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/pgcrypto.html#AEN119292

Comment: _“What I actually want do is a double hash hashing the sha1 hashed password into bcrypt.”_ - that does not sound like a good idea though. By basing this on the already SHA1-hashed values you have, you would be reducing the realm of input characters _massively_, as compared to a normal password entered by the user, which would (ideally) contain special characters, and upper and lower case letters.

Comment: There are a bunch of examples on this site for how to do this properly, just search for password upgrading or migrating. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39411173/231316

Comment: @CBroe Upon login I would hash it again from plaintext. On login I will check whether is double hashed or not and I will update the password using single bcrypt hash.

Comment: But then why do you need to do it preemptively for all users to begin with? You could just do that the next time the user logs in … Do they have a value stored in your new bcrypt password column yet? If so, use that; if not, fall back to the SHA1-hashed value stored in the old password column to verify their login this once, and then _set_ the new bcrypted password at that point (here you should still have the original user password, they just entered it via the login form), and clear the old SHA1 one (so that can’t be used again in the future.)

Comment: Some users rarely login at all thereore unti user logins or changes password I want an intermediate solution. Also due to business rules I'll hafta keep the credentials.

Comment: "Therefore do you know a faster way to hash all user passwords in postgresql with a postgresql-native password updating?"  PostgreSQL does have  blowfish hashing in the pgcrypto extension.  But it is not going to be fast.  That is the point of using it.  If the slowness were optional, there wouldn't be any point.

Answer (score -2):

In order to update the passwords en marre run the following sql:

```
UPDATE users SET password = crypt(users.password,gen_salt('bf')), double_hash=true;
```

Ensure password field is at least 72 characters long. Upon sucessfull login rehash the provided password using `password_hash`.